# Fig 1.8 on page 16 of Guillemin and Pollack's "differential topology"

Tags: differential-geometry

For fig 1-8 on page 16, there is a sentence explaining why it is not a submanifold: "The trouble arises because the immersion is not one-to-one". I am quite confused because the definition according to page 14 "the best we can demand is that $df_x : T_x(x)\to T_y(Y)$ be injective. If so, $f$ is said to be immersion at $x$" means that immersion is already one-to-one in tangent space. But does Fig1.8 show this injection in tangent space ?

[image: page 16]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The injectivity of any $df_x$ in any tangent space $T_x(X)$ does not imply that the map $f$ is injective, i.e. that $x\neq y\Rightarrow f(x)\neq f(y)$, as the example of the "eight" proves. In fact, in that case, there exist $x,y\in S^1$ with $x\neq y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. However the maps:
$$
df_x:T_x(S^1)\to T_z(\mathbb R^2),\qquad df_x:T_y(S^1)\to T_z(\mathbb R^2)
$$
with $z=f(x)=f(y)$ are injective. The point is that $ T_x(S^1)$ and $T_y(S^1)$ are *different* tangent spaces which are *injectively* mapped into the same tangent space $T_z(\mathbb R^2)$.
The fact that $df_x$ is injective implies only that  in a neighborhhod $U_x$ the restriction $f|_{U_x}$ is injective. However may exist $y\not\in U_x$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: So I have a very simple question. The tangent space at point $z$, namely the intersection point in figure eight, $T_z(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is basically $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself. I am thinking it is a line tangential to this "eight" shape. If so, $ T_z(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is not even well defined for the obvious 2 choices there.

Comment: No,  $T_z(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is a *plane*, that is basically $\mathbb R^2$ as you said. Why do you say it is a line? The 'lines' are actually the images of $T_x(S^1)$ under $df_x$  and  $T_y(S^1)$ under $df_y$: they form two intersecting line subspaces of $T_z(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: OK. I understand. Thanks for your excellent explanation.:)